# Subtraction in a column that has vacant cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

The column `A` has many empty cells. In the adjacent column `B`, I want to subtract the value of (say) `A5` from `A10`. `B10` would contain the result.

There are may blank cells in between cells with values. The number of blank/empty cells vary.

Comment: It isn't clear yet what you are asking.  Perhaps an image of some fake data could help explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Put you numbes in column A with the negative simbol. then do a sum. So B10 = sum(A1:A5)

Comment: It isn't clear how this addresses a problem of empty cells (whatever that ambiguous problem is).  [from review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/699640)

Answer (score 0):

So use if() and isblank():

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A5),ISBLANK(A10)),"",A10-A5)
```